# Consequentially perform several ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need to make several ajax call consequentially, e.g., request #2 should be made only after successfully finished request #1. We can make it in jQuery as mentioned here [How to handle several ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901130/how-to-handle-several-ajax-requests)
But is there any way to do it in vanilla javascript?

Comment: You can use [Promise](https://github.com/then/promise) library separately for organizing your AJAX calls.

Comment: This answer has vanilla javascript to make an ajax call.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557247/easiest-way-to-retrieve-cross-browser-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback function.

Quoted from: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_callback.asp

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
     document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
```